# Show a bounded operator is scalar multiple of identity operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

let $A\in B(H)$  such that $TA=AT$ for all $T\in B_0(H)$ where $B_0(H)$ denote the set of all compact opeartors on $H$.

show that $A=\alpha I$ where $\alpha $ is some complex number.

i have approach it by let $(e_i)$ be orthonormal basis of $H$. then consider projection $P_i$  on closed subspace $W_i = <e_i>$, spane of $e_i$.

then we have$$AP_i=P_iA$$

gives $$A(e_i)=\alpha_i e_i$$ for scalar $\alpha_i$. now how can we say that these $\alpha_i$ are all equal.

is this method right or some better way to do this problem

thanks in advanced

Comment: Try to show it for $2 \times 2$ matrices.

Comment: @gerw i am not gettting. can u please explain a bit more

Comment: You should try to prove: if $A \in \mathbb R^{2\times 2}$ satisfies $T A = A T$ for all $T \in \mathbb R^{2\times 2}$, then $A = \alpha I$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is certainly not enough: any "diagonal" operator $\sum\alpha_iP_i$ will commute with all your $P_i$.

But you have scores of other finite-rank operators. In particular, for fixed $k,j$, let $X$ be the rank-one operator that maps $Xe_j=e_k$. Then 
$$
\alpha_ke_k=AXe_j=XAe_j=\alpha_jXe_j=\alpha_je_k,
$$
thus showing that $\alpha_k=\alpha_j$.